# Node Subpath Imports External Directory

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

In [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-alias)/[WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias), we can define path aliases fairly easily, and we can even use the `@` to define these.  However, in an ESM Node app, it's not as easy.  There's module-alias, but it's a little outdated, and [doesn't work](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias/issues/123) for ESM packages.  All of this led me to [Subpath Imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports).

Subpath Imports seem to work just fine (except I can't use `@` instead of `#`) with files/directories in the package.json's directory, but it doesn't seems to work with directories outside.  e.g. this is my `imports` config in `package.json`:

```
"imports": {
  "#api/*": "./*",
  "#shared/*": "../shared/*"
}
```

The `#api` works properly, but the `#shared` does not.  Is there some sort of extra config that I'm unaware of, or is this not possible with Subpath Imports?  I know the docs say `it is possible to define internal package import maps that only apply to import specifiers from within the package itself`, so if it's not possible, what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution that works a little better.  I'm using an [npm workspace](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces), which actually allows me to use the workspaces as if they're absolute paths.  My directory structure is as follows:

```
root/
  api/
    app.js
    package.json
  shared/
    test.js
    package.json
  ui/
    package.json
  package.json
```

In the root `package.json`, I have specified the `workspaces` config to be the following:

```
"workspaces": [
  "ui",
  "api",
  "shared"
]
```

And then in `app.js`, I can reference something from shared like `import test from "shared/test.js"`.  I didn't realize this added benefit of workspaces, but it definitely solves the issue I was having.